# Run Angular code before page rendering with Phantom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, render

I have written a script to give me some information of a specific page, unfortunately I cannot get it's angular code to fully run before I render it. The code is accessing the right page, but not angular code is ran before the rendering is done from Phantom side. Here is the bit of code:

```
var page = new WebPage()
var fs = require('fs');

page.customHeaders = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('user:pass')
};
page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 800
};
page.open("https://address", function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        page.render("valued.png");
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time});
});

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    console.log("Page load finished");
    // page.evaluate(function() {});
    var content = page.content;
    console.log('Content: ' + content);
    phantom.exit();
};
```

I cannot use `page.onCallBack` as I am not the author of that specific page, so I cannot call my Phantom code when the page is fully redenered. Any ideas?

I even tried to set a bigger timeout and I can see the rendered page, but with no content loaded:

```
var page = new WebPage()


page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 800
};

page.customHeaders = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("user:pass")
};

page.open("https://address", function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        page.render("valued.png");
        phantom.exit();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Can it be just an error in Angular app, probably due to the lack of browser polyfills or whatever? Would be a reasonable explanation. Any way, I don't think that anything can be suggested without having http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You're the only person who knows what this page is and what happens there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, reasonable enough. The website is working fine on Chrome, but on Phantom I got that weird template issue. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could try to catch errors and console calls from the page to debug it. Depending on what's your case, it would probably make sense to switch from Phantom to Nightmare. The latter isn't headless but performs better.